# Insert Options for a child item via the experience editor

Tags: experience-editor

We build composable pages where the page has a child item folder that contains the details for how the page is to render (and the appropriate content)

I'd like to make the Experience Editor give the insert options for the Page Content folder and on selection insert the new item in the Page Content folder.

It will be triggered by the User via a button in the experience editor.

Is there a way to trigger the insert option dialog for a child item?

[image: Sitecore Tree Structure]
[image: Sample UI]

Answer (score 1):

You can add insert option to standard values of child item.
[image]

Comment: The question is how do I access them from the experience editor. The content editor is no problem.

Comment: You set insert options for child item. It will appear when you click add component in exeperience editor. About the component is added via button, please use placeholder.

Comment: right but we are editing the parent item of the item where the insert options are configured. In this case: The Page Content folder has it's insert options configured, but when you edit the item in the experience editor, you're editing the "Apply" item.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is the on the rendering itself, you can add the experience editor buttons for Insert, delete, sort etc like so?

[image: Rendering UI options]

Which will enable these options in the Experience Editor:
[image]

If you use the "insert" option and you've specified the insert options, you'll be able to add child items like this.